# Dynamically read class names and pair / append matching divs

Tags: jquery, class, dynamic, append, grouping

I've looked at many posts about doing vaguely the same tasks individually and I get the basic concepts, but I'm wondering how to put it all together into one clean script. I think the trickiest part is getting a certain classname from div, parsing that certain classname and matching it with another classname elsewhere that has a matching letter sequence.

The situation, simplified for clarity: Many dynamic divs with multiple classes / separate parents:

```
<!— visible - holds filterable portfolio grid of logos —>
<div id="portfolioGrid">
  <div class=“ portfolio_item project_tag-client_name ” > Logo </div>
  <div class=“ portfolio_item project_tag-diff_client_name ” > Logo </div>
  <div class=“ portfolio_item project_tag-other_client_name ” > Logo </div>
</div>

<!— invisible separate div, holds tooltip contents —>
<div id="tooltips" style=“display:none”>
  <div class=“ portfolio_tooltip info_client_name ” > Project Info </div>
  <div class=“ portfolio_tooltip info_diff_client_name ” > Project Info </div>
  <div class=“ portfolio_tooltip info_other_client_name ” > Project Info </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to:

**1)** Dynamically find whole class names of classes that contain “project_tag-...“. In other words, "Find divs with class "project_tag-*anything*". Only need that one class, particularly the *anything* variant - Wordpress adds "project_tag-" prefix.

**2)** Find div inside “#tooltips” with matching “info_*anything*”.

**3)** Append “info_client_name” divs inside the matching “project_tag-client_name” divs.

**4)** Do all that dynamically without knowing a client_name so that it happens automatically when a new portfolio item / tooltip is created. Preferably with jQuery/JS.

The reason for doing this is so that I can give my non-comp-saavy client an easy/clear editing modules in WP, allow easier CSS manipulation for me, plus make it nearly automatic as long as class client_names match. I already have a tooltip that loads each respective info_content and pops up on hover/tap a logo, but having them under separate parents complicates things for CSS.

Also, feel free to let me know of any better ways of doing this, maybe I'm over thinking it. I dig learning.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your questions, I am trying my best to get the answer.

**Answer 1**

```
$('[class^="project_tag-"]').css('color', 'red');
```

**Answer 2**

```
$('#tooltips [class^="info_"]').css('color', 'red');
```

**Answer 3**

```
$("[class='info_client_name']").appendTo($("[class='project_tag-client_name']"));
```

**Answer 4**

You can replace `client_name` with dynamic one.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I can definitely move them "manually" with jQuery, but I'd like to automate it with a script that uses a RegEx or something to fond the matching names and put the divs together. I'lll attach a screenshot / diagram to further clarify.

Comment: It would be a very useful script that I could repurpose for other areas / projects.